# Invalid attempt to access field before calling read()

Tags: c#, mysql, database

I have searched for a good couple hours now, looking for a solution to this problem. I am trying to get information from my database using the code below with the correct queries. I know these queries work because I have tested them in MySQL workbench. I keep getting the error:

> Invalid attempt to access field before calling read()

As you will see, I do call read(), and my research has only come up with not using the correct database, which I have also verified to be correct already. Any ideas as to why I am receiving this error? Thanks in advance for the help.

```
public static string ExecuteSelect(string query)
{
    //Example query is: SELECT entity_id FROM catalog_product_flat_1 WHERE sku='itemSku';
    string statement = "";

    MySqlCommand myCommand = new MySqlCommand(query, _conn);

    MySqlDataReader myReader;
    myReader = myCommand.ExecuteReader();
    myReader.Read();

    statement = myReader.GetString(0);
    myReader.Close();

    return statement;
}
```

Comment: Have you checked the return value of `Read()` is it returning true (indicating there are results to be read) or false (indicating there are not).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Not sure if this is the problem in your case, but you should always check the result of Read().  eg

```
if (myReader.Read())
{
  statement = myReader.GetString(0);
}
```

**Edit:** Also what you are actually doing is retrieving a scalar, and as such you could use ExecuteScalar()

```
return (myCommand.ExecuteScalar() ?? string.Empty).ToString();
//also rename your method appropriately
```

Comment: That is a good point. I added this and will keep it, but unfortunately it did not solve my issue

Comment: @SubxZero So it passes the `if()` and still throws the error?  Are you positive that column 0 is actually a string type?  Try doing `statement = myReader.GetValue(0).ToString()` and see if that succeeds.

Comment: Actually, I added your first suggestion in the wrong spot of my code and corrected it, and it worked. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

I have just walked away from a similar issue as yours.My solution was to use a

```
if (!myReader.HasRows)
                {

                }
```

just before walking through the dataset.

```
while(myRead.Read()
{
 //read tuples
}
```

This would mean for your code:

```
public static string ExecuteSelect(string query)
{
//Example query is: SELECT entity_id FROM catalog_product_flat_1 WHERE 
sku='itemSku';
string statement = "";

MySqlCommand myCommand = new MySqlCommand(query, _conn);

MySqlDataReader myReader;
myReader = myCommand.ExecuteReader();
myReader.Read();
if(!myReader.HasRows)
{
 //set your statement variable to some generic value
 statement="abracadabra";
}

while(myReader.Read())
{
statement = myReader[0].ToString();
}
myReader.Close();

return statement;
}
```