# Using dates between VB and SQL

Tags: mysql, database

I am building a school project which is a room booking service. I have reached the part of the programming where I need to figure out how to store bookings. I know how to pull from a database using VB and I've laid it out like that when I try to pull booking information from the database.

```
    strBookingQuery = "SELECT * FROM bookings WHERE Date = '" & InputBookingDate & "'"
    Dim Cmd As New MySqlCommand(strBookingQuery, Newconnection)
    Newconnection.ConnectionString = strServerString
    Newconnection.Open()
    reader = Cmd.ExecuteReader()
    reader.Read()

    StartPeriod = reader.GetInt16(1)
    Length = reader.GetInt16(2)
    UserID = reader.GetInt16(3)
    RoomID = reader.GetInt16(4)
    Newconnection.Close()
```

But when it gets to StartPeriod = reader.GetInt16(1) it says Invalid attempt to access a field before calling Read(), is this because MySQL stores dates in a different way? Or something else? Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: since you have mentioned *`is this because MySQL stores dates in a different way`*.... assumed that `StartPeriod` is a `date` type column. Please comment if it's not, if so my answer isn't valid.

Answer (score 1):

How do you expect [GetInt16](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatablereader.getint16%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) to read a `date`?

> **Reader.GetInt16() gets the value of the specified column as a 16-bit signed integer. No conversions are performed; therefore, the data retrieved must already be an Int16 or coercible to an Int16.**

Given that OP confirmed there's no issue with startPeriod, the possible issue could be:

[Invalid attempt to access field before calling read()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11089633/invalid-attempt-to-access-field-before-calling-read)

Comment: Ah apologies I forgot to include an earlier bit of code. Where it says InputBookingDate that's reading from a Date variable. Start Period, Length, UserID and RoomID are all just integers.

Comment: Please add that code as well. Further, can you confirm that you are only returning `Start Period, Length, UserID and RoomID` and they are in order? If not please show the entire query plus the columns you are pulling out.

Comment: InputBookingDate = DateTimePicker1.Value.Date
^ I did this to isolate it so it was just a date.
            GetBookingData()
^ That runs the function which is the code I previously showed.

    Public BookingDate() As Date
    Public StartPeriod As Integer
    Public Length As Integer
    Public UserID As Integer
    Public RoomID As Integer
 ^ These are the variables which they are being stored to.