# Invalid attempt to access a field before calling Read(). code not working

Tags: c#, mysql, c#-4.0

```
string query2 = "Select * from books where Book_code=";
query2 = query2+ "'" + textBox2.Text + "'";

cmd = new MySqlCommand(query2, con);
MySqlDataReader d2 = cmd.ExecuteReader();
d2.Read();

if (d2.GetString(0).ToLower() == textBox2.Text.ToLower())
{

}
```

when ever go in if condition it gives an exception Invalid attempt to access a field before calling Read() while i am also using d2.read().

Comment: Learn how to format the question. You need to use MySqlCommand Parameters.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11089633/invalid-attempt-to-access-field-before-calling-read

Comment: Can you tell why you need to compare again with `textBox2.Text`?

Comment: i was thinking some times textbook2.text will some value and the query result will return nothing as may b there is no record as textbook2.text value. so i compare it if the given reslut and the textbook reslut will some then do some action .. HassanNisar

Comment: i was thinking some times textbook2.text will some value and the query result will return nothing as may b there is no record as textbook2.text value. so i compare it if the given reslut and the textbook reslut will some then do some action .. @HassanNisar

Comment: Then  you could make  use of `if(d2.HasRows)`, if this statement is false then nothing is returned otherwise you iterate through rows. Still comparing with `d2.GetString(0)` is bit odd.

Comment: Solved... @HassanNisar

Answer (score 1):

It is recommended to use `Parameterized Query` to avoid SQL Injection attacks.

Also note that `MySqlDataReader.Read()` return `boolean` value.
It will read records row by row for you. It should be executed while the reader reaches to the last retrieved row.

```
string query = "Select * from books where Book_code=@BookCode";

cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, con);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BookCode", textBox2.Text);

using(MySqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())                   
{
     while(reader.Read())
     {
         if (reader.GetString(0).ToLower() == textBox2.Text.ToLower())
         {

         }
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should *always* use [parameterized queries](http://blog.codinghorror.com/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death/). This kind of string concatenations are open for [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks.

[`MySqlDataReader.Read()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.read%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method read your `MySqlDataReader` row by row. You are getting this error probably because you can't read your data reader fields without iterate it. You can use it like;

```
while(d2.Read())
{
   if (d2.GetString(0).ToLower() == textBox2.Text.ToLower())
   {
       //
   }
}
```

Also use [`using` statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) to dispose your `MySqlCommand` and `MySqlDataReader` as well.

```
using(MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(ConnectionString))
using(MySqlCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand())
{     
    cmd.CommandText = "Select * from books where Book_code = @code";
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@code", textBox2.Text);
    using(MySqlDataReader d2 = cmd.ExecuteReader())                   
    {
        while(d2.Read())
        {
            if (d2.GetString(0).ToLower() == textBox2.Text.ToLower())
            {
                 //
            }
        }
     }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should check the result of `Read`:

```
if (d2.Read())
{
    if (d2.GetString(0).ToLower() == textBox2.Text.ToLower())
    {
    }
}
```

Note, that `DbConnection`, `DbCommand` and `DbDataReader` descendants are implementing `IDisposable`. You should dispose them via [`using`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us//library/yh598w02.aspx) blocks.