# VB.net and SQL .... For multiple read of database table

Tags: vb.net

Im am currently coding an handsfree RFID attendance monitoring system where i could just swipe and record details automatically...

I've been in trouble about this piece of code where i need to fetch a table and another table inorder to check if there is an existing record in table1 as the details and table2 as a record in in/out. I wanted it as much as possible to be able to be in a 1 while loop
**
I kept getting this error **

**Invalid attempt to access a field before calling Read()**

`

```
 Private Sub TextBox7_KeyDown(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles TextBox7.KeyDown
        If e.KeyCode = Keys.Enter Then

            'Dim idnum = Val(TextBox7.Text
            Dim statu As String = ""
            Dim idnum = (TextBox7.Text)
            Dim record As String = ""

                TextBox2.Text = ""
                TextBox3.Text = ""
                TextBox4.Text = ""

                ConnectToDB()
            sql = "select * from rfidmaintest.student_details_dub where f9  = '" & idnum & "'"
                cmd = New MySqlCommand(sql, cn)
                dr = cmd.ExecuteReader

                While dr.Read

                    TextBox2.Text = (dr("f2"))
                    TextBox3.Text = (dr("f9"))
                    TextBox4.Text = (dr("f4"))
                    TextBox5.Text = (dr("f14"))
                    TextBox6.Text = (dr("f3"))
                TextBox7.Clear()
                dr.Close()
                cn.Close()

                'ANOTHER FETCH
                ConnectToDB()
                sql = "select * from rfidmaintest.monitoring where id_num  = '" & idnum & "'"
                cmd = New MySqlCommand(sql, cn)
                dr = cmd.ExecuteReader


**Invalid attempt to access a field before calling Read()**

                If (dr("entry_record")) = String.Empty Then
                    status.Text = "IN"
                End If

                If status.Text = "IN" Then
                    status.Text = (dr("entry_record"))
                    record = "OUT"
                ElseIf status.Text = "OUT" Then
                    record = "IN"
                ElseIf status.Text = String.Empty Then
                    record = "IN"
                End If
            End While
            dr.Close()
            cn.Close()
```

`

I tried to call the table

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Invalid attempt to access field before calling read()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11089633/invalid-attempt-to-access-field-before-calling-read)

Comment: What exactly is confusing you about the error message? It's telling you exactly what the problem is. You obviously know that you need to call `Read` on a data reader because you're doing it earlier in that same code.

Comment: im sorry im not familiar with c# tho @RohadBokhar

Comment: That said, your code has some serious issues and you really need to go back to the drawing board. You assign a data reader to `dr` and then start a loop based on that variable, then you assign something else to that same variable within the loop. That's never going to work. If you have two different commands to execute then use two different variable for them and for the data readers they generate. That's still probably not going to work unless you have enables multiple active result sets in the connection string though.

Comment: @jmcilhinney hey sir sorry if i annoy you.... I have fixed the problem.... I ended in separating the whole section of code where I need to call from another table...

Comment: My issue is questions being asked without reasonable steps having been taken first. Sometimes it appears that people have not even read the error message they copy into their question, let alone copied it into a search engine to see what information is already out there on the subject. That sort of thing needs to be done before a question is posted here, which should be a last resort.

Answer (score 0):

You need another dr.read for the second query or you can use another reader, for example like dr2.read.
Your first While dr.read already closed with dr.close, you need to reopen the reader to continue to read the second query

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).